# How can i retrieve the live location of a gps module to my database so that i can use it in multiple apps?

Tags: gps, video-streaming, tracking, agora.io

I want to track a vehicle and send its coordinate locations to multiple mobile devices at the same time. Is there a way to do that? i also need to send the live feed of the buses' current location  Can i do it with agora.io?

Answer (score 0):

[Agora Aignaling SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Signaling/product_signaling?platform=All%20Platforms) is perfect for this

You can get started through their [demos on Github](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Signaling) for different platforms.